# How can i retrieve random row each time PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

i want to implement a "**varification**" feature to take user to certain page thus i have verification table on my database with the following columns

1. Id
2. Code
3. Used_code
4. Status

So `code` column has random numbers, after they are used they will be moved to used codes, and `status` column will have 0 or 1 to determine whether the code have been used or not.

At first i thought it was a good idea to create `used code` column so that when a person enter the codes they will be checked if they are used first and throw an error.

Please guys if you have any suggestions please share with us whether to use a for loop etc however for loop will not retrieve random row its okay just something that retrieve new id each time and check whether row status is used or not, just anything guys. Thnx.

Comment: How many rows are there and what's the maximum number of rows that you anticipate you'll ever have?

Comment: I have 1000 rows, 10,000 is the max

Answer (score 0):

Your new feature doesn't necessarily require a new table if its included in another module. For verifying users, I would have a verified column in the users row with a code. Once a unique link is visited and verified by the user with the secured code by any means, I would set the verify to NULL.

If your implementation is different like a rewards system, you might as well have ['id' => $myId, 'usr' => $user, 'code' => $code, 'used-status' => true || false] Remember MySQL structures are open-source, you can ask the databse whatever question you want. You just have to update your tables application-wide.

To determine if the code is used with your structure, I recommend an UPDATE query. The INSERT should occur when your function fires via ajax or http.

```
//INSERT: This occurs when the user clicks enter and a random code is sent to the database and the user's email and/or phone
$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO activity (id, usr, code, status) VALUES ('{$UNIQUEID}', '$userid', '0314f5s4f14', 0)") ? null : die();

//UPDATE: This occurs when the user clicks the link in their text messages or email which sets the code to used status.
$update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE verification SET status='1' WHERE 
id='".$_SESSION['id']."'") ? null : die();

//HINT: use json for client to server applications, research progressive web apps.
$data = array('_POST' => $_POST, '_SESSION' => $_SESSION, 'sql' => $sql, 'dlt' => $dltq);
print json_encode($data); unset($data); mysqli_close($con);
```